# Dog continually licking thighs

Tags: dogs

My oldest pet dog (male, 2.5y/o, shih tzu/bichon mix) has had a little bit of a problem lately, he will not stop licking his thighs.

We've done this:

- given him small doses of dog benadryl (we thought it might be allergies)
- given him pain medication (we were told from an emergency clinic that his knees might be graded, but the chiropractor and his vet seem to think he's healthy)
- tried to rub his thighs for him and stretch out his leg a bit

Here is a video of how "extreme" it is

[image]

(he will do this for upwards of 5 minutes at a time), and here's a picture of the aftermath:

[image]

Things we think that it may be:

- this summer was his first time getting a summer cut that trimmed off almost all of his fur (normally we leave him a little bit, but this summer was warm). Maybe it's itchy? We have a second dog, one year younger, exhibiting no such issues though.
- he's bored (he used to lick his paws, so we started letting him take a bone to bed, etc), but this seems to be going on a bit long for boredom
- he's allergic to something
- he's actually in pain (he does not express pain with yelping like our other dog does)
- or, the worst case, his knee *is* actually in a bad situation and needs to get surgery or some such.

At this point, we're genuinely at a loss of what could be wrong with him, since we're getting conflicting information from the professionals that take care of him. Is there anything I'm overlooking that *could* be wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the information from the professionals? Also, a visit to the vet is probably overdue.

Comment: @Roflo he's been in and out of the vet a few times in the past few months for this same issue. They say nothing is wrong every time (probably because they can't observe the behavior). We've taken him to an emergency clinic when he had a really bad episode and there they said that he's got graded knees. The chiropractor we took him to gave him an adjustment, but said that he seems to be otherwise healthy. No one seems to know why he keeps licking his thighs though.

Comment: Well, I'm not qualified to diagnose, but I wouldn't rule out anxiety.

Comment: @Roflo that's kinda what we've been thinking. It can't be too bad, because if we put our hand between him and his thigh, he'll lick our hand instead - which makes me think it's not about soothing any pain.

Comment: You could try putting an e-collar on him for a while and seeing if the behavior eventually stops.

Comment: @KevinHu it hasn't been happening lately. that said, we're really not sure what changed his behavior. we're going to go with a combination of allergies and anxiety, as we've been trying to spend more time with him lately as well, and he seems to have taken to it.